# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby

Trying to start an https server with the following code:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'
include WEBrick

root = File.expand_path './public'

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read 'cert.crt’
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read 'pkey.pem’


server = HTTPServer.new(
  :Port => '4430',
  :DocumentRoot => root,
  :SSLEnable => true,
  :SSLCertificate => cert,
  :SSLPrivateKey => pkey)

trap('INT') { server.shutdown }

server.start
```

It raises this error:

```
test.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read 'pkey.pem’,
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you even read your own question? The syntax highlighting even shows you the exact error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in line:

```
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read 'cert.crt’
```

you have an opening single quote and  then a different kind of quote-like character around `cert.crt`.

By the way, you also have the same error in line:

```
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read 'pkey.pem’
```

around `pkey.pem`, which is not detected, but will be when you correct the first error.